# vuejs store localStorage set object

Tags: vue.js, local-storage

I have a theme config store, and I set "localStorage" on this store, I can read it the same way. but I'm recording them one by one, is it possible to send them all as objects instead, if possible, please give an example.
how do i set it on the store
I'm a little newbie in storage, please comment accordingly.

```
export const $themeConfig = {
    app: {
        appName: 'Name', 
        appLogoImage: '', 
    },
    layout: {
        skin: 'light', 
        type: 'vertical', 
        contentWidth: 'full', 
        menu: {
            hidden: false,
            isCollapsed: false,
        },
        navbar: {
            
            type: 'floating', 
            backgroundColor: 'dark',
        },
        footer: {
            type: 'static', 
        },
        customizer: true,
    },
}
```

```
import {$themeConfig} from '../../themeConfig'

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        layout: {
            skin: localStorage.getItem('themeConfig-skin') || $themeConfig.layout.skin,
            type: localStorage.getItem('themeConfig-menuLayout') || $themeConfig.layout.type,
            contentWidth: localStorage.getItem('themeConfig-contentWidth') || $themeConfig.layout.contentWidth,
            menu: {
                hidden: localStorage.getItem('themeConfig-menuHidden') || $themeConfig.layout.menu.hidden,
            },
            navbar: {
                type: localStorage.getItem('themeConfig-navbarType') || $themeConfig.layout.navbar.type,
                backgroundColor: localStorage.getItem('themeConfig-navbarBG') || $themeConfig.layout.navbar.backgroundColor,
            },
            footer: {
                type: localStorage.getItem('themeConfig-footerType') || $themeConfig.layout.footer.type,
            },
        },
    },
    getters: {},
    mutations: {
        UPDATE_SKIN(state, skin) {
            state.layout.skin = skin

            localStorage.setItem('themeConfig-skin', skin)

            if (skin === 'dark') document.body.classList.add('dark-layout')
            else if (document.body.className.match('dark-layout')) document.body.classList.remove('dark-layout')
        },

        UPDATE_LAYOUT_TYPE(state, val) {
            localStorage.setItem('themeConfig-menuLayout', val)
            state.layout.type = val
        },
        UPDATE_CONTENT_WIDTH(state, val) {
            localStorage.setItem('themeConfig-contentWidth', val)
            state.layout.contentWidth = val
        },
        UPDATE_NAV_MENU_HIDDEN(state, val) {
            localStorage.setItem('themeConfig-menuHidden', val)
            state.layout.menu.hidden = val
        },
        UPDATE_NAVBAR_CONFIG(state, obj) {
            if (obj.backgroundColor)
                localStorage.setItem('themeConfig-navbarBG', obj.backgroundColor)
            else
                localStorage.setItem('themeConfig-navbarType', obj.type)
            Object.assign(state.layout.navbar, obj)
        },
        UPDATE_FOOTER_CONFIG(state, obj) {
            if (obj.type)
                localStorage.setItem('themeConfig-footerType', obj.type)
            else
                localStorage.setItem('themeConfig-footerType', obj.type)
                Object.assign(state.layout.footer, obj)
        },
    },
    actions: {},
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist

Comment: I like to work without being tied to a package. I don't want to use package

Comment: @Liza What is the motivation? You could start with reimplementing Vue this way. Any way, vuex-persist or vuex-persistedstate is the answer. If you're willing to reinvent a wheel for some reason, consider checking their source code

Comment: Exactly as Estus says. It is your choice if you use the package directly or you read it's code to learn how to do it yourself. It's not complicated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Store Objects in HTML5 localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/how-to-store-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 1):

You can create helper functions like:

```
function updateThemeConfig (key, data) {
  let state = localStorage.getItem('themeConfig');
  if(state){
    state = JSON.parse(state);
    state[key] = data;
  } else {
    state = {
      [key]: data;
    }
  }
  localStorage.setItem('themeConfig', JSON.stringify(state))
}

function getThemeConfig (key) {
  let state = localStorage.getItem('themeConfig');
  if(state) {
    state = JSON.parse(state);
    return state[key];
  }
  return;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
footer: {
  type: getThemeConfig('footerType') || $themeConfig.layout.footer.type,
},
...
UPDATE_LAYOUT_TYPE(state, val) {
  updateThemeConfig('menuLayout', val); 
  state.layout.type = val
},
```